# multiple statements in if condition in xquery

Tags: xquery

I am writing a function in xquery in which i want to return an if else statement. I am trying the following
let's say :

**return
if (somevalue eq 1) then (some-method($var1, $var2,....), "RandomValue"
else
(do... this..)**

What i want here is, i want the if condition to run and when somevalue is eq to 1 then it should first call the some-method() function and then append "randomvalue" after it.. {basically my code is building a sql statement). Although the above that i have tried is giving me error that "expecting else" but I think that i should be able to do multiple things inside the if statement (if whatever is there in the if condition is true then). So how can I achieve that?

Comment: Try to avoid temporal language when using functional programming languages. Don't assume that (X, Y)  "first" does X and "then" does Y - it does X and Y in some order of its own choosing and concatenates the results.

Answer (score 2):

The query seems to be nearly complete. Multiple expressions can be wrapped in parentheses:

```
...
return if (somevalue eq 1) then (
  some-method($var1, $var2,....), "RandomValue"
) else (
  do... this..
)
```